# Google Music (Play) and Chrome

Tags: sound, streaming

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 and it's taken me forever and a day to get the surround sound working on my system using the Creative Labs Audigy SE card.

Now that I have the sound working correctly, I'm having an issue with streaming my music from Google Play, using Chrome and Firefox. Firefox won't stream it at all. And with Chrome, the music is like a 33rpm record on 45rpm speed.

It's very very choppy, static, sounds like the chipmunks took a bottle of speed.

Anyone else stream music from Google Play? I can stream my movies via the Plex Media server perfectly fine. All speakers come through. But I stream my music when i'm working. Right now I can't do that.

I don't want to have to try 200 fixes as the last time i ended up re-installing and working on a few just to get my sound to work. I don't want to loose it again.

Comment: I'm new to this, and you lost me on that.  Especially the self answered question  part.

Comment: Found the issue. Had to disable the HTML5 Audio in the Labs portion. Once I did that, it plays fine.

Answer (score 4):

Solution given by OP in comments:

> Had to disable the HTML5 Audio in the Labs portion. Once I did that, it plays fine.